# Volatile и кеши процессора

Tags: java, многопоточность, volatile

Здравствуйте, вот возник такой вопрос. Насколько я понял, переменные Volatile обязаны быть постоянно записаны в память. А если обычная переменная, то она, как правило, хранится в кеше процессора для более быстрого доступа. Собственно при использовании Volatile записывается напрямую в оперативку.

Есть, скажем, какой-то процессор на 4 ядра. Соответственно 4 независимых процессора, у каждого из которых свои кеши, например, первого и второго уровня, а третий общий. Ну, собственно, запустили несколько потоков. Допустим, каждый из них работает на отдельном ядре, у которого свой кеш. Делаем переменную Volatile, и она пишется напрямую в память. А теперь если запустить программу на одноядерном процессоре, то ОС имитирует параллельность потоков. Выходит, что кеш у процессора один и все потоки работают на одном процессоре. Вопрос вот в чем. Переменная обычная кешируется на уровне процессора или на уровне программном? То есть если даже одно ядро и запущенно несколько потоков, то они делят кеши процессора на независимые области памяти, имитируя многоядерность. Или же они используют один и тот же кеш вместе, значит, переменная Volatile не имеет смысла? 
Объясните, пожалуйста, как все происходит. Спасибо.

**EDIT**

Я имел ввиду, что переменная для быстрого доступа не пишется сразу в память, например, *x*=1  не будет сразу записана в память, так как на это нужно много тактов процессора, а будет по возможности записана в кеш процессора, а уже потом записана в память. Если не поставить volatile и если потоки будут одновременно менять ее, то новое значение будет сохраняться в кеш, а не напрямую в память писаться. Если потоки работают на нескольких ядрах, то все понятно, у каждого ядра свой кеш, и если попытаться прочитать,  и при этом последнее значение хранится в каком-то кеше, то получим не то, что надо, если, конечно, не из того потока читать, который последний записывал. А вот если на одном ядре, то кеш ведь один и все потоки туда пишут, тогда смысл от volatile? Или я что-то не так понимаю.

Comment: `Volatile` ничего не известно о кешах процессора. Для `volatile` известно только то, что она, по возможности, не должна храниться в регистрах. Кэши - это уже более низкий уровень. Вам что хотелось бы прояснить, как ведет себя `volatile` или как работают Кэши?

Comment: Ну, я имею ввиду, что обычная переменная ведь в кеше хранится для быстрого доступа. То есть при попытке чтения, если много потоков ее изменили, то у каждого своя кешированная, и при попытке прочитать будет не то, что надо. А как на одноядерном происходит, если кеш у процессора один, по сути все потоки пишут туда, тогда смысл от volatile?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> То есть при попытке чтения если много потоков ее изменили, то у каждого своя кешированная и при попытке прочитать будет не то что надо.

При чтении каждый процессор будет видеть локальную копию "переменной в памяти" (из своего кеша), а вот при записи в такую переменную, он сообщит остальным процессорам, что те должны обновить свои кеши **в заданной кеш-линии** перед последующим чтением.

Обычно, такие отношения дают свойство [когерентности кэша](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Когерентность_кэша). Есть процессоры, которые обладают таким свойством, а есть и такие, для которых требуется адаптировать код, чтобы сохранить целостность данных. И одним `volatile` тут не всегда можно обойтись ([на ARM'ах, например](http://habrahabr.ru/post/155507/)).

p.s.: только это, опять же, к `volatile` не имеет отношения. Грубо говоря, это свойство разделяемой памяти [SMP-архитектуры](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Симметричная_мультипроцессорность).

---

> в этой архитектуре, нет места кэшам и проч. занудствам о которых вы пишете с таким завидным упорством

[[@Barmaley](/users/5648/barmaley)](/users/5648/barmaley), я вот еще немного поразмышлял на тему "нет места кэшам и проч. занудствам" и все таки прихожу к выводу, что без этих знаний Вы врят ли **даже на `java`** можете расчитывать на адекватные характеристики производительности Вашего кода для `SMP`. Вот [пример из жизни, с массивами](http://habrahabr.ru/post/211747/).

Но когда я искал этот материал я вообще-то думал даже не о каких-то особенностях строения массивов, а о банальной **параллельной обработке классического массива**: делим массив на `n` частей и обрабатываем каждую в своем потоке (с какой-то долей записи в массив, конечно же, т.е., например: "параллельное заполнение данных").

Если Вы не подумаете в рамках этой, простой на первый взгляд, задачи о возможности **вытеснения кеш-линии** соседним процессором, и порождаемом при этом [кеш-промахе](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Кэш_процессора#.D0.92.D0.B8.D0.B4.D1.8B_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.BC.D0.B0.D1.85.D0.BE.D0.B2), то не получите для нее адекватных результатов (насколько я знаю, `java` пока не умеет читать мысли программиста и добавлять `padding'и` под границу кеш-линии для массивов, которые он решит распараллелить таким образом).

Comment: Вопрос про java. Одного volatile достаточно, что бы другой поток увидел последнее записанное значение.

Comment: В контексте `java` - конечно. Скорее всего. Согласен.

Comment: @mega, есть 2 категории программистов: одни, которые разрабатывают нечто новое, а вторые, улучшают/вылизывают написанный 1-мы неэффективный код. Приведенный вами пример, по массивам, это яркий пример для кодеров 2-й категории. Если заметили, я называю 2-х кодерами, а первых таки разработчиками. Улавливаете разницу? 

Поддержка параллельных вычислений в Java никакая - это верно. Впрочем для этого есть специальные языки и пытаться делать распараллеливание классическими языками - по меньшей мере неразумно. С развитием мультикорных процессоров я думаю мы увидим другие и парадигмы программирования

Comment: Ваша дифференциация вульгарна - не самый лучший способ аргументации. Как мнение - заслуживает внимания, но не более. Сами же понимаете, такие радикальные взгляды не могут быть популярны. Нет, конечно, если у вас своя философия на программирование - не имею ничего против: сколько людей, столько и мнений. Я лишь высказал свое, с практической, как мне кажется, точки зрения. Насколько я понимаю, мы с Вами слишком разные, чтобы найти взаимопонимание в этом вопросе.  
 --  
Кстати, если переживаете о минусе - напрасно, он не мой.

Comment: А вот касательно "поддержки параллельных вычислений в Java никакая" и "распараллеливание классическими языками - по меньшей мере неразумно", как сказал автор статьи: "тоже повод для беседы".

Comment: @mega, я прекрасно знаю чей минус :) - это от уважаемого @avp, которого я отлично знаю и безмерно уважаю. Ну а в том, что мы разные - это да. Я приверженец классической школы программирования и предпочитаю, действительно не заморачиваться *когерентными кэшами*, а упор больше на алгоритмической составляющей. Важность *когерентных кэшей* я не отрицаю, но они важны для других программистов. 

По-поводу дифференциации - это я вынес в том числе и из лекции Гослинга, на которой мне посчастливилось как то присутствовать. Почитайте его интервью, дискуссии - там часто встречаются такие мысли.

Comment: >Важность когерентных кэшей я не отрицаю, но они важны **для других** программистов.

Вот это Вы очень правильно добавили! Собственно, этим мои претензии и исчерпаны по этому вопросу. Спасибо за понимание!  
 --  
По поводу Гослинга, ничего не скажу против. Идолы у всех разные, а мнение по радикальной дифференциации - мое личное. Как говорится, разделять Вам лично его совсем не обязательно, а вот слушать, увы - приходится Всем :)

Comment: @Barmaley, Вы правы, минус мой. 

Уж больно (IMHO) не в тему 

(дело тут не в Java, а в том, что по сути-то ТС интересуется *"а как на самом деле все это работает"*) 

ответ.

--

И конечно, `volatile` не только (и даже не столько) с когерентносью кэшей связан, просто чтобы понять это автору надо сначала разобраться в том, что такое когерентность кэшей.

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужно разбить поток мыслей на вопросы. Пока простой ответ который можно дать - volatile не связан с кешем.

> Ну я имею ввиду обычная переменная ведь в кеше хранится для быстрого доступа?

Нет. Правильно думать о кеше и памяти, как о едином месте. Если что-то есть в кеше, оно есть и в памяти (+- пару исключений). В большинстве современных ширпотребовских системах кеш неуправляем, поэтому про него можно просто "забыть". (Если вы программист высоких материй, то можно и не вспоминать).

> А как на одноядерном происходит если кеш у процессора один по сути все потоки пишут туда, тогда смысл от volatile?

Volatile - это высокоуровневый примитив, на котором в java основана MemoryModel, он нужен на любом количестве процессоров, ядер и потоков. (Размер кеша, его количество, иерархичность не влияют.)

Comment: Опередили немного :)

Answer (score 4):

У volatile есть один плюс - он требует, что бы значение переменной всегда читалось с памяти. А в эту память может писать не только процессор...

Или второй вариант - есть jni код, который модифицирует переменную, а java код только читает. И чтобы оптимизатор не выкинул чтение, нужно дописать volatile.

Answer (score 3):

[[@Alexandr Crospov](/users/14325/alexandr-crospov)](/users/14325/alexandr-crospov), для ответа на свои вопросы (они глубже, чем уровень Java) поразбирайтесь с  преобразованием виртуальных адресов (именно ими оперирует CPU) в физические (ключевое слово -- MMU),

а потом с когерентностью кэшей (начните с ссылки в ответе [[@mega](/users/8766/mega)](/users/8766/mega)).

--

Кстати, когда говорят о потоках, то обычно подразумевают, что все *потоки* находятся в одном пространстве виртуальных адресов, а вот у каждого *процесса* (в нем может быть несколько потоков) свое виртуальное адресное пространство.

Answer (score 2):

Молодой человек - современное программирование построено на т.н. [архитектуре Фон-Неймана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C0%F0%F5%E8%F2%E5%EA%F2%F3%F0%E0_%F4%EE%ED_%CD%E5%E9%EC%E0%ED%E0) - почитайте про это.

Там, в этой архитектуре, нет места кэшам и проч. занудствам о которых вы пишете с таким завидным упорством. Место хранения переменной зависит от конкретной реализации конкретного компилятора - так что не забивайте себе голову.

Comment: Зря Вы так, уважаемый :) С момента зачатия `multicore` многое изменилось.

Comment: Угу - но это все уже изыски на уровне компилятора, но никак не разработчика.

Comment: Так ведь разработчики разные бывают. Кто-то - на высоком уровне работает, кто-то - на низком. Или Вы не считаете таких за разработчиков?

Comment: @mega речь идет вообще то о Java, а не об ассемблере. Напомню таки, что Java работает поверх виртуальной машины JVM, в котором отсутствуют понятия кэша процессора и проч.

Comment: В контексте `java` - согласен, уже писал для @IronVbif. Не согласен только с Вашим обобщением. Вопрос на стыке интересов, поэтому, думаю, не стоит так категорично замахиваться на современное программирование :)

Comment: >в этой архитектуре, нет места кэшам и проч. занудствам о которых вы пишете с таким завидным упорством

@Barmaley, я еще немного расширил [свой ответ](http://hashcode.ru/questions/354761#354779) по этому поводу.