# Java Где хранится volatile переменная

Tags: java, многопоточность, volatile

Всегда думал что volatile переменные в Java хранятся в MetaSpace, недавно на собеседовании мне сказали что это неверно. Так вот вопрос: где они хранятся?

Comment: enSo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350974/volatile-keyword-the-thread-local-memory

Comment: @Max Wood [тут уже описано](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/354761/volatile-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Даже интересно, откуда у вас могла возникнуть такая мысль. В метаспэйсе, как и следует из его названия, хранятся описания типов, а не данные. За исключением разве что констант. Данные хранятся либо в стеке, либо в куче. Изредка в нативной памяти. Так как модификатор `volatile` может применяться только к полям, то волатильные значения всегда будут в куче.